# Picture Mapping & jQuery .show() + .hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a bit unsure what is going on here. I've doubled checked everything but there is still a critical problem with the script.

The central problem is everything works, but when I click on hideLabels portion of the picture, the jquery for that id does not execute. Everything else does! All the other area maps work for both pictures. But for some reason hideLabels doesn't. But showLabels does.

```
 <section id="picture">
        <img src="alberta.jpg" usemap="#mapper"></img>
        <map name="mapper">
            <area id="pcalgary" shape="circle" coords="103, 266, 6" href="#" alt="Calgary">
            <area id="pedmonton" shape="circle" coords="113, 187, 6" href="#" alt="Edmonton">
            <area id="plethbridge" shape="circle" coords="133, 303, 5" href="#" alt="Lethbridge">
              <area id="pmedicinehat" shape="circle" coords="164, 290, 4" href="#" alt="medicine_hat">
              <area id="ppeacerivercity" shape="circle" coords="50, 114, 5" href="#" alt="peace_river_city">
              <area id="preddeer" shape="circle" coords="106, 231, 4" href="#" alt="red_deer">
              <area id="pbowriver" shape="circle" coords="127, 272, 11" href="#" alt="bow_river">
              <area id="pathabascariver" shape="circle" coords="133, 103, 15" href="#" alt="athabasca_river">
              <area id="psaskatchewanriver" shape="circle" coords="149, 181, 13" href="#" alt="saskatchewan_river">
              <area id="ppeace_river_river" shape="circle" coords="70, 52, 14" href="#" alt="peace_river_river">
              <area id="pathabasca_lake" shape="circle" coords="164, 36, 13" href="#" alt="lake_athabasca">
              <area id="pslave_lake" shape="circle" coords="82, 128, 14" href="#" alt="slave_lake">
              <area id="showLabels" shape="rect" coords="2, 286, 58, 320" href="#" alt="labelpicture">
        </map>
    </section>

    <section id="labels">
        <img src="albertab.jpg" usemap="#mapper"></img>
        <map name="mapper">
            <area id="pcalgary" shape="circle" coords="103, 266, 6" href="#" alt="Calgary">
            <area id="pedmonton" shape="circle" coords="113, 187, 6" href="#" alt="Edmonton">
            <area id="plethbridge" shape="circle" coords="133, 303, 5" href="#" alt="Lethbridge">
              <area id="pmedicinehat" shape="circle" coords="164, 290, 4" href="#" alt="medicine_hat">
              <area id="ppeacerivercity" shape="circle" coords="50, 114, 5" href="#" alt="peace_river_city">
              <area id="preddeer" shape="circle" coords="106, 231, 4" href="#" alt="red_deer">
              <area id="pbowriver" shape="circle" coords="127, 272, 11" href="#" alt="bow_river">
              <area id="pathabascariver" shape="circle" coords="133, 103, 15" href="#" alt="athabasca_river">
              <area id="psaskatchewanriver" shape="circle" coords="149, 181, 13" href="#" alt="saskatchewan_river">
              <area id="ppeace_river_river" shape="circle" coords="70, 52, 14" href="#" alt="peace_river_river">
              <area id="pathabasca_lake" shape="circle" coords="164, 36, 13" href="#" alt="lake_athabasca">
              <area id="pslave_lake" shape="circle" coords="82, 128, 14" href="#" alt="slave_lake">
              <area id="hideLabels" shape="rect" coords="2, 286, 58, 320" href="#" alt="nolabels">
        </map>
    </section>
```

Then I have my jQuery script.

```
  $('.content').hide();
$('#labels').hide();

         $("#showLabels").click(function(){
         $('#picture').hide();
         $('#labels').show();
});
         $("#hideLabels").click(function(){
         $('#labels').hide();
         $('#picture').show();
});
```

**Edit**
**What the script is supposed to do**

Basically there are 2 pictures of a map. One without labels (#picture) one with (#labels). The site shows #picture and not #labels. if you click on the picture map #showLabels. the script hides the #picture and shows #labels. (this works) then when you have the #labels picture presented. when you click on the picture map #hideLabels the picture switches back so hide(#labels) and shows (#picture).

**Problem**
The problem is when on the labels picture. When I click the id (#hideLabels) nothing happens.

**What I have tried.**

When I replace the id="1" to the map element #hideLabels and the jquery. still does not work. However, when do this in the jquery it does work.

```
      $("#labels").click(function(){
         $('#labels').hide();
         $('#picture').show();
});
```

the #labels refer to the whole section that involves the picture. So clicking on the picture does work.

But this is not the function I need. I really need the click to work on the specific rect map. So it seems like the click function is not working for the concept map #hideLabels, but why, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Try to put all your script inside 

`$(document).ready(functiion() {

});`

Comment: Can you tell us what is supposed to happen?

Comment: document ready did not work. (even with the spelling corrected). I edited the post to say what is supposed to happen.

Comment: See new edits. It appears that it is the click function that isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your map doesn't actually change (you're using the same map name), and I see that it's that same thing twice (ignoring labels) so what I would do is just have a toggle not two separate maps

EXAMPLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/dwkgsu79/

```
  $('.content').hide();
  $('#labels').hide();

     $("#toggleLabels").click(function(){
     $('#picture').toggle();
     $('#labels').toggle();
 });
```

You'll have to guess where the buttons are

Comment: Actually you're right. This works much better. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

you are using the same id for both of the mappers.

Change the id of the second mapper.

Comment: Spot on. Thanks so much!